# Executing a CASE statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Query takes two tables does a left join, then filters out based off preferences.  It runs well, however, when I add the 'case' statement I run into issues. The idea was to grab the first digits I need to classify them into a broader category. I need to be able to change the names of a field into something friendly. Any suggestions?

Values for the tr.TENANT_NAICS field follow a format similar to this:

1. 543330- Other Computer Related | 2782 Science
2. 548972- Socials

Would like to change to just:

1. Other Computer Related
2. Other Computer Related

Query

```
 
select 

tr.OCCUPANCY_DATE, tr.END_DATE, tr.TENANT_NAICS,  

pr.PROPERTY_STATUS, pr.NRA_BUILDING, pr.MARKET, pr.SUBMARKET, pr.FULL_ADDRESS_ONE_LINE,
pr.LEGAL_OWNER, pr.TRUE_OWNER,

lr.LESSOR_SUBLESSOR,

/* trying to fix here */
(case
when left(tr.TENANT_NAICS, 2)::numeric = 11 THEN 'Other Computer Related'
when left(tr.TENANT_NAICS, 2)::numeric = 21 THEN 'Mining'
when left(tr.TENANT_NAICS, 4)::numeric = 4821 THEN 'Construction'
    else tr.TENANT_NAICS
end) as "Tenant Industry"

from space.tran tr

left join property pr on tr.ID = pr.ID
left join lease lr on tr.OID = lr.OID

where 
tr.STATUS = 'Existing' and tr.MARKET = 'Seattle' 
;
```

Edit: the exact error I receive is 'Numeric value 'Bu' is not recognized'.

Comment: What issues do you run into with the CASE statement? Please update your question with the logic/rules you are trying to implement - assuming they are not what you have in your CASE statement

Comment: @NickW I updated my title and included the error I receive. I'm just unsure how the logic is not working. I have a separate query that runs using a similar case statement mentioned and it works fine

Comment: Somewhere in your `TENANT_NAICS` column you have entry that starts not with a number but with the string `Bu`. So you are trying to do `'Bu'::numeric`, essentially telling snowflake to convert `Bu` to a number, and it's not liking that command. Consider using `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_TO_NUMBER` instead of `::numeric`. with those, if the casting fails it will merely return a `NULL` and your logic will work.

Comment: @JNevill thanks, i tried using try_cast but i got this error 'SQL compilation error: Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types BOOLEAN and NUMBER(2,0)'. This was what my statement looked like (CASE
WHEN TRY_CAST((left(tr.TENANT_NAICS, 2) = 11) as int) THEN 'Agriculture, Foresetry, Fishing and Hunting'
    ELSE tr.TENANT_NAICS
END) as "Tenant Industry"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently TENANT_NAICS is a varchar column and there must be at least one value that starts with BU instead of digits. Try this SQL:

```
select 

tr.OCCUPANCY_DATE, tr.END_DATE, tr.TENANT_NAICS,  

pr.PROPERTY_STATUS, pr.NRA_BUILDING, pr.MARKET, pr.SUBMARKET, pr.FULL_ADDRESS_ONE_LINE,
pr.LEGAL_OWNER, pr.TRUE_OWNER,

lr.LESSOR_SUBLESSOR,

/* trying to fix here */
(case
when left(tr.TENANT_NAICS, 2) = '11' THEN 'Other Computer Related'
when left(tr.TENANT_NAICS, 2) = '21' THEN 'Mining'
when left(tr.TENANT_NAICS, 4) = '4821' THEN 'Construction'
    else tr.TENANT_NAICS
end) as "Tenant Industry"

from space.tran tr

left join property pr on tr.ID = pr.ID
left join lease lr on tr.OID = lr.OID

where 
tr.STATUS = 'Existing' and tr.MARKET = 'Seattle' 
;
```

Comment: Wow, I thought because the first characters pulled were numbers they had to be cast to numeric. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well.. this makes a lot more sense than `try_cast` I suggested.